# Add 2 arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that look like this:

array 1:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => name
        [1] => age
        [2] => job
    )
```

array 2:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => name
        [1] => toan
        [2] => age
        [3] => 21
        [4] => job
        [5] => coder
    )
```

Now, I would like to take the values from keys `0, 2, 4` and make those values their own keys that point to the values in keys `1, 3, 5` in the array, like so:

```
Array
(
    [name] => toan
    [age] => 21
    [job] => coder
)
```

What is simple and fast way to do this?

Comment: Well, implement a small function using a loop and iterate through the second array using `array_keys()` and `array_key_exists()` or `is_set()`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array_combine($array1, array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

#### [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2lb1uw)

Comment: Nice! I normally go for something that doesn't require a loop but that escaped me.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that value is followed by key in array 2, which it would need to be to use array 1 anyway, you don't need array 1:

```
foreach(array_chunk($array2, 2) as $pair) {
    $result[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}
print_r($result);
```